Would it be better to use fseek + ternary or an IF?
fseek( pChunk, (iCurChar < 31) ? ftell(pChunk)+((31-iCurChar)+1) : ftell(pChunk), 0 );

If the condition is not met we shouldn't move anywhere in the file. Which would go easier on the resources: having this ternary, or making an if that doesn't do basically nonsensical "fseek( ftell() )"?
I think the difference on modern machines is pretty much negligible but I'm really not sure what I should go for. The resource management is pretty important here so I would go for as little as possible, even if it's negligible.
I looked at what people say about them and some of the opinions differ. This case is pretty unique, I think, because there's also an extra operation in play with the ternary (the fseek to ftell). I don't know how big of a difference it will be and I have no experience in benchmarking whatsoever.

Write clear and concise code, and leave micro-optimisations to the compiler. It's not immediately obvious what your code does.

Why are you fseeking at all when you don't need to? if (iCurChar < 31) { fseek(pChunk, 32 - iCurChar, SEEK_CUR); } seems like what you want, and reduces two unconditional system calls to a single conditional call. Fewer system calls is a big(ish) deal, this nonsensical attempt at branchless code (that still branches) doesn't seem to serve any purpose, and any "savings" it might make will be more than eliminated by even one additional system call.

Why are you using 0 for the third parameter? fseek is specified to take a value of SEEK_CUR, SEEK_END, or SEEK_SET. It looks like you think 0 might be SEEK_SET, but that is neither clear to readers nor portable.

As @ShadowRanger indicates, the ternary version is still a branch/conditional (potentially generating an assembly branch or conditional jump).  To elaborate, it seems you are under the impression that ternaries have better performance than an equivalent if statement.  That is very unlikely in a modern optimizing compiler.

Did you compare the assembly of the two versions?  Did you profile them?  Was there a significant difference to justify even caring about this?

I've never found the ternary operation easy to parse, and rarely use it. It's just a shorthand version of if ... else.

@WeatherVane About the only use I've ever found for any ternary operator is in the context of things like arguments to *printf() where a NULL must be avoided.  Like prinf( "some arg: %s", arg ? arg : "<null>" );  Other than that, they are downright evil, making an unreadable mess out of code.

Even quick web searches lead to the conclusion that ternaries have very limited use. This case is definitely not one. Don't you have coding rules to follow?

Although proclamations about code style are quite often subjective matters of opinion, I feel pretty confident in saying that the form
if(iCurChar < 31)
    fseek(pChunk, (31-iCurChar) + 1, SEEK_CUR);

would be unarguably preferable in every way.  The ternary operator has its uses, but this isn't one of them.
In general, the ternary operator is useful when you need to do something conditionally, but in a context where for whatever reason an if statement is not an option.  But here, in deciding whether to call fseek or not, an ordinary if statement is definitely an option — it's the preferable option!
There's nothing to be gained by calling fseek unconditionally and then, via the "false" branch of your ternary operator, contriving to have that fseek call sometimes not do anything.
fseek is a fast call already, since basically all it does is adjust pointers or offsets into the file being read.  So there's almost no percentage in trying to speed up a call to fseek.  It's not clear what slim advantage you might have imagined could be gained by using the ternary operator (and some unnecessary ftell calls) in this way, but I can tell you that the advantage is not "slim"; it is nonexistent (or negative).  Even in the most resource-constrained environment, the clean-and-obvious form should be fine.
